# Searching using BinarySearch

Tags: java, binary-search

I tried to run this code to search for a name by using the binary search, but it's not working.
What's wrong with this code or method?

```
 public static int BinarySearchForStudentsName(String StudentName[],String Name) {
    int left = 0;
    int right = count - 1;
    int middle;
    while (true) {
        middle = (left + right) / 2;
        int copmarison = Name.compareTo(StudentName[middle]);
        if (Name.equals(StudentName[middle])) {
            return middle;
        } else if (left > right) {
            return count;
        } else {
            if (copmarison > 0) {
                middle = middle + 1;
            } else {
                middle = middle - 1;
            }
        }
    }
}
    public static void main(String[] args) {
String a[]={"A","B","C","D"};
int index = BinarySearchForStudentsName(a,"M");
    if (index == count) {
        System.out.println("not found");
    } else {
        System.out.println("founded at " + index);
    }
}}
```

Comment: 1. There is no value named "Me" in your array. 2. The array needs to be sorted before searching.

Comment: Am sorry i forgot sorting array when i wrote it but the same thing still not working ....
and about the value "ME" i want to taste it if it'll return not found or not ... So why searching ?

Comment: `String StudentName[]` can't be right. Your variable `copmarison` is spelled wrong. Your variable `count` is undefined. Fix this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to update the `left` and `right` values not the `middle`..change it like this

```
while (true) {
    middle = (left + right) / 2;
    int copmarison = Name.compareTo(StudentName[middle]);
    if (Name.equals(StudentName[middle])) {
        return middle;
    } else if (left > right) {
        return count;
    } else {
        if (copmarison > 0) {
            left = middle + 1;
        } else {
            right = middle - 1;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Looking for a name, you take a phonebook. Open it in the exact middle. There are 3 possibilities:

1) you're lucky, you found the name, end of search.

2) The name is 'greater' (alphabetical ordering). Rip off the left half of the phonebook and re-start.

3) The name you're searching is 'smaller'. Rip off the right half of the phonebook, re-start...

What's wrong with the code?

1) BinarySearch requires a sorted array:

```
String a[]={"Aureliano","Cruise","Hatchi","Zaboumba"};
```

2) The return value of 'compareTo' should guide the search, not a comparison as "left>right". "CompareTo" returns 0, or returns something < 0, or returns something > 0.

3) If the searched name does not exist, at some point there'll be no pages left in the phonebook. Likewise, your code should not use an infinite loop: instead of 'while(true)', think about a condition involving the variables 'left' and 'right'.